# CSS grid classes in angular ant design system

Tags: antd, ant-design-pro, ng-zorro-antd

I would like to know the performance of plain CSS classes compared to ant-grid components & directives.

Can someone help me to find ng-ant design system CSS documentation like bootstrap?
I am using ng-zorro-antd framework to build Angular application. In my application there are many places where i just want to use grid using css like bootstrap provides.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">col</div>
  <div class="col">col</div>
  <div class="col">col</div>
</div>
```

I know ant provides same thing with angular component **Row** and **Col**.
Example:

```
<div nz-row>
      <div nz-col nzSpan="12">col-12</div>
      <div nz-col nzSpan="12">col-12</div>
</div>
```

```
<nz-row [nzGutter]="16">
    <nz-col [nzSpan]="12">

    </nz-col>
</nz-row>
```

**Need to know about performance of CSS based grid Vs component or directive based**

Ideally prefer css grid for designing complex layout.

Comment: Hi Saurabh and welcome to Stackoverflow, next time please pay attention to the quality of your question. Take a look at highly voted ones to see some good examples. Also, I highly recommend you to read the linked blogpost, on how to write high quality questions:  https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/#presentation

Comment: Thank you @Uwe Keim  for the suggestion